# Wheel build sanity check

Tags: wheels

Am a little scared now.

It's a 700c rim am trying to build. Trouble is it's an offbrand Rodi rim so there isn't any official data I could use.

I measured between spoke hole to spoke hole and it came in at around 575mm.

I used two 270mm spokes took a measurement at the valve hole from J-bend to J-bend it came in as 44mm. Spun the rim 90 degrees then measured it came in as 45mm.
hence a 584mm ERD.

Edd spoke calculator tells me:

```
Spokes              36
Crosses             3
Spoke length left   278.5 mm
Spoke length right  277.3 mm
```

but the guy at the bike shop says these number are more typical of 650b.
However it's definitely specd to be a 700c rim as the tyres say so.

It's a deep sectioned rim though (time to use a guide spoke).

Should I just go ahead?

Comment: Presumably you are using https://www.parktool.com/blog/calvins-corner/measuring-effective-rim-diameter to measure the ERD

Comment: You haven't given any dimensions of the hub.  As EDD says "There are five hub dimensions: dL, dR, S, WL, WR"  which are documented at https://leonard.io/edd/howtomeasure

Comment: Once you've got two spoke lengths from EDD repeat everything with http://wheelspoking.com/Build.aspx?Mode=Basic and they should be very close.   Spokes are normally available with 1mm or 2mm increments, so even half a millimetre can be disregarded.

Comment: Yes I am using calvin's method.  Thanks criggie.  It does come within 2mm the measurement wheelspoking.com spits out.  So I guess he was just being cautious and I didn't instil alot of confidence in him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My method for measuring ERD is simple for a normal wheel or a deep section aero wheel.

Feed a white or light-coloured string through two spoke holes directly opposite each other.  Count the empty holes on either side to be sure.

Then thread a nipple onto the string on one side.  Knot string behind nipple and pull string so it sits in the proper place.

On the other end of the string, thread enough nipples so that the first one pokes through the rim and sits normally.

Use hand tension to take the slack out of the string, but not so much it stretches.

Use a permanent marker to dot the string where it enters the second nipple.

Release it all, and then measure from the knot to your dot, and add the height of one nipple.

Note if you have access to the base of the second nipple then dot there and don't bother adding an offset of one nipple height.

Then repeat this in two more places around the rim - bare rims can be quite out of round, so averaging three results should get you a more accurate number.

Comment: @Swifty whoops - brain and fingers seem slightly disconnected atm :)  Goot catch.

Answer (score 1):

Check your ERD measurement. Maybe show your bike store guy if you want a second set of eyes on you procedure.

Check your spoke length calculations with a different calculator.

Proceed. THere's only one way to learn, and that's by doing.